# PHPUnit doctrine mock issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

ideally for my project I need to store time only in the database (doctrine type="time_immutable"). However it causes issues with phpunit and I cant find any working solution.

When I try to mock time only got this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '09:00:00' for column 'start_time' at row 1
```

When mock datetime got this error:

```
Could not convert database value "1970-01-01 09:00:00" to Doctrine Type time_immutable. Expected format: H:i:s
```

It works fine when I do actual API call, so seems like issue with phpunit only. When I change doctrine column type to datetimetz_immutable and mock datetime it works fine for tests but obviously I have to store entire datetime when I need time only.

Comment: I have no idea at all what you are doing, show us the test code that is throwing the error, I do not know what do you mean with mocking time and not working, it should be a carbon instance and done.

Comment: I realized it may not be Laravel, but Symfony, so I am removing the laravel tag until a test is shared...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, I had to manually delete testing schema. I believe there was some cached issue with that schema.

Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: You never mentioned if it is Symfony or Laravel

Comment: How this could help you? The error response are directly from phpunit and doctrine dependency. There is no laravel problem

Comment: You had a laravel tag originally in your question, which I removed...